# My minecraft folder does not have files in it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-mods

I am trying to install mods, but when I click my minecraft folder, there is nothing inside except the "mods" folder I manually created. I installed Forge for 1.7.10, and when I go onto minecraft, the forge logo is there with the extra "mods option". Yes, the mod I tried (opitfine) is for 1.7.10 and is compatable with forge. But when I log onto minecraft, it still only says I have the 3 mods forge gives you. Please help!

Comment: So are you saying there are no files under ".minecraft" except for the mods folder?

Did you put the optifine mod into your mods folder?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no other folders in your folder, than that is not the directory Minecraft is running off of.

By default, your Minecraft folder would be located at `%appdata%\.minecraft`. Otherwise, if you think it somehow got changed, you can find your Minecraft directory by going to your launch profile settings:

- **New Launcher:** Go to the tab labled "Launch options". Click on your Forge profile and you should see the row labled "Game directly". Press the arrow (which should give you the text "Go to folder" when you hover over it) to go to your Minecraft directory you have set for Forge.
- **Legacy (Old) Launcher:** Make sure you have your Forge profile selected in the profile selector (lower left corner). Click "Edit Profile" and you should see  the row near the top which says "Game Directory:". Your Minecraft directory for Forge will be in the input field.

If you do not see the mods folder there, you can manually create it.